# How do I use strong induction (the second principle of finite induction) to prove $a^n - 1 = (a-1)(a^{n-1} + a^{n-2}+ \cdots + a + 1)$???

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, induction

$$a^n - 1 = (a-1)(a^{n-1} + a^{n-2}+ \cdots +  a + 1)$$

I have no idea how to use "strong induction" to prove this, I have used an example like $a^{3}-1$ but I'm assuming that is not what the answer is looking for by any means! Help! It's apparent that when you use $a^{n-1} -1$ that it works, but how can this be mathematically proved using this method. I feel like it has something to do with proving it for $n < 1$ because the equation is for all $n$ is greater than or equal to 1.

Comment: This can be proven fairly cleanly using normal induction, but strong induction seems a bit overkill.  Is there a source that is specifically instructing you to use strong induction?

Comment: Hint: $\;a^n-1=a^n \color{red}{-a^{n-1}+a^{n-1}-1}=a^{n-1}(a-1)+(a-1)(\cdots)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base case: $n=1$. In this case, the LHS is $a^{1}-1=a-1$ and the RHS is $1$, so the result holds.

Inductive step: fix $n\geq 2$ and assume the result holds for all $k<n$. We want to show the result holds for $n$. If $a=1$, the LHS and the RHS are both $0$, so the result follows. If $a\not=1$, we may divide both sides by $a-1$. Thus, we need only prove that
$$
\frac{a^{n}-1}{a-1}=a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}+\cdots a+1.
$$
But this follows since
$$
\begin{aligned}
a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}+\cdots a+1&=a^{n-1}+(a^{n-2}+\cdots +a+1)\\[5pt]
&=a^{n-1}+\frac{a^{n-1}-1}{a-1} &&\quad\text{by the inductive hypothesis}\\[5pt]
&=\frac{a^{n-1}(a-1)+a^{n-1}-1}{a-1}\\[5pt]
&=\frac{a^{n}-a^{n-1}+a^{n-1}-1}{a-1}\\[5pt]
&=\frac{a^{n}-1}{a-1}.
\end{aligned}
$$